# Difference between 2 approach of encryption

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, secret-key

I want to encrypt my content with SecretKey, here is 2 solution I found:

```
String password = "javapapers";
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");
SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

byte[] salt = new byte[8];
Random random = new Random();
random.nextBytes(salt);

int iterations = 100;
PBEParameterSpec pbeParameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterations);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, pbeParameterSpec);

String input = "something";
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
```

And the second one:

```
String password = "javapapers";
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
Random random = new Random();
random.nextBytes(salt);

int iterations = 100;
PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, 256);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC";);
SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
String ivStr = "0123456789abcdef";
iv = ivStr.getBytes("US-ASCII");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

String input = "something";
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
```

As you can see in the first approach, when creating PBEKeySpec, I just need to pass the password.toCharArray(). After that, a PBEParameterSpec is created with the salt and iterations.

But in tthe second approach, when creating PBEKeySpec, I need to pass password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations. Beside that, instead of PBEParameterSpec, they use IvParameterSpec when initializing the cipher.

So my question:

Where should I pass salt, iterations to? In PBEParameterSpec (first approach) or PBEKeySpec (second approach)? And the different between them?

Comment: 3DES and AES comparison?

Comment: No, I just cannot understand the different between 2 approachs (about where to pass to salt and iterations to). Please ignore the algorithm

Comment: You can use `PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC` with both approaches. The main difference I see is that in the 1st approach the key and IV are derived from the password (afaik via PKCS#12), while in the 2nd approach the IV can be explicitly specified. Both codes return the same ciphertext if the same salt and IV (`cipher.getIV()` from the 1st approach) are applied.

Comment: `PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES` is an Oracle proprietary extension to the password-based encryption defined in PKCS#5 (RFC 8018) to support longer keys. It is outdated and should no longer be used (except for compelling compatibility reasons), s. kelalaka's comment.

Comment: Hi @Topaco, so that where should I pass Where should I pass salt, iterations to? In PBEParameterSpec (first approach) or PBEKeySpec (second approach)?

Comment: With explicit IV you have to use the 2nd approach, without explicit IV the 1st approach (of course with `PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC` instead of `PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES`). Both should be similarly secure. However, I can't say definitively which is more secure (intuitively, I would consider the independent IV to be more robust). [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41438) you can find a post about the security of an IV derived from a password, but for PBKDF2.